# how to create a carousel in a fragment

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to assemble a carousel inside a fragment, but I can't find a tutorial or anything like that.

Now I just need the Fragment, could someone help me?

I followed this site: https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-a-carousel-in-android-using-kotlin/

but in his case, he does the code in an AppCompatActivity class

I would like to do the same, only in a Fragment class

if possible instead of text I would like an image

Comment: Just do it in your fragment's `onViewCreated`. It does not matter if he does it in his MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ViewPager2 in fragment without problems, but you should initialize ViewPager's adapter in onViewCreated method. If you want an image simply change TextView to ImageView in item_carousel.xml mentioned in article that you provided.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).